# Manually adding a UDID to Xcode 10?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, xcode10

Is there any way to add a UDID manually (one determined via iTunes) to the Apple Developer Portal and the Team Provisioning Profiles? I added the UDID to the Portal, and to all the manual Profiles, but I can't seem to get Xcode to update my app's Team Provisioning Profile to reflect the new UDID.

It seems to have worked in the past when connecting a device to Xcode and letting it set up that device, but I can't do that in this instance (the device is with a team member in another state).

Comment: After adding the device to the profile in the portal, download it and then drag and drop it onto Xcode

Comment: That’s for manual profiles. How do I get it to add to the Team Profile?

Comment: See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88871